# Get index of list of dictionaries while iterating through it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

I am using python v3.6.

I have a list of dictionaries which look like this;

```
dictionary_list = [{'f1': 'name1', 'f2':'1', 'f3':'4'},    
                  {'f1': 'name2', 'f2':'2', 'f3':'5'},
                  {'f1': 'name3', 'f2':'3', 'f3':'6'}]
```

I have a simple for loop to iterate through this list of dictionary. I need to access the index of the list but this information is lost inside the loop. How do I modify the for loop to access the index?

```
for i in dictionary_list:
    #How to access the index in the dictionary_list
pass
```

Comment: Why do you need the index?

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Why the negative vote? I would like to know to ask the right questions on stackoverflow in future.

Comment: Bah, got notified about your comment, thought you had answered my question. Sigh. I didn't ask that for fun, btw. I'm not convinced you really need the index. You wouldn't exactly be the first person ever to [ask for Y when you really need X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann, I need the index to keep count. Sorry, I don't know why providing that information would be useful since I already got the answer from TerryA by the time you comment. Thanks for dropping by, anyway.

Comment: Well it could be useful if you don't actually need the index. While `enumerate` certainly does the Y that you asked for, it might still be the wrong approach to do the X that you're really after. Again: you wouldn't be the first to do that. Not sure what "keep count" means, that doesn't really answer the question. But ok, whatever. Anyway, if you indeed want to do the right things here, I recommend not ignoring people who are trying to help.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann, thank you very much for your help. Upvoted your comment. Apologies for ignoring the comment as I was busy with other stuff then. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, j in enumerate(dictionary_list):
    print(i, j)
```

This will print:

```
(0, {'f1': 'name1', 'f2': '1', 'f3': '4'})
(1, {'f1': 'name2', 'f2': '2', 'f3': '5'})
(2, {'f1': 'name3', 'f2': '3', 'f3': '6'})
```